# Hovering over an image changes HTML background

Tags: css, html, hover, background-image

Basically:

```
div:hover
{
body{ background-image:(bg.png); }
}
```

This is logical code, I know it does not work, but its the best how I can show you my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In css ,You can not do this as "body" is parent element to "div" and it should come next to the element hovered to use the for format like

```
firstelement:hover second_element {/*styles*/}
```

you can use jquery to achieve it

```
$("div").hover(function(){
    $("body").css("background", "url('url_of_image_here')")
});
```

or javascript

```
   elem = document.getElementById("ID");
   elem.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){   
      document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundImage="url()";
     });
```

Comment: `elem = document.getElementById("ID");
elem.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundImage="url()";
});`
I wanted to revert back to blank, here's what I added, thanks for the code!

Answer (score 4):

Well what your trying to accomplish cannot be achieved that way using Css only, You can do it using jquery like this

```
$("#someDiv").hover(function(){
    $("body").css("background-image", "url('image_url')")
});
```