# change the background image by "hovering" over a div in css

Tags: css, background, hover, background-image, mousehover

trying to get my code to change the background image to "color.jpg" when "spiral.svg" is being hovered over. I think im getting closer, definitely missing something but not sure what that is!

HTML

```
   <div class ="spiral">
       <img src="spiral.svg">
    </div>
```

CSS

```
img {
    max-width: ???;
    max-height: ???;
}

.spiral:hover {
    background:url('color.jpg') center;
    z-index: some positive number higher than my orig background image?
}


body {
   background:url('orig.jpeg') center;
   z-index: -60;
}
```

Comment: `z-index` works when `position` is specified.

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this.

```css
.twitter{
  display:block;
  border:1px solid red;
  width: 30px;
  height:30px;
  background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/qM7IYaM.png?1);
  background-position:-32px 31px;
  transition:0.1s;
}

.twitter:hover{
   background-position:-32px 63px;  
}
```

```html
<div href="https://twitter.com/georgevere12" class="twitter">
  
</div>
```

Comment: ah yes this works, but im trying to target the <boby> tag. my hover img is actually small and im trying to have it replace the orig background image when being hovered over. starting to think it just might not be possible without js/jquery

Comment: you may scale the image using css on hover. By default it will be same as your specified size and on hover scale it to fit on screen with the colored image.

Comment: I can get it to change the scale of the image, but this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26822311/hovering-over-an-image-changes-html-background?rq=1 I was reading says it is not possible to target the body tag for this with just using css if im reading it correctly, gonna try some jquery

Answer (score 0):

looks like this is not possible with just CSS/HTML however this was the best link i found using a tiny bit of jquery https://stackoverflow.com/a/19770298/5225450